# Phonegap using pt instead of px

Tags: css, cordova, pixel, units-of-measurement

I'm currently working on a PhoneGap app and I'm testing it on an Android Samsung Galaxy S2 but I want to target Android and iOS.

I want a fixed header and according to http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html headers on the iPhone are `44pts` high. Since I don't want to reinvent the wheel I thought it's a reasonable size and I use it as well.

I have the following in my index.html (note the `target-densitydpi=device-dpi`)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

And the following CSS

```
header {
    height:40pt;
    padding:2pt 0;
}
```

But when I deploy the App to my Phone and taking a ruler to measure it, the header is almost exactly `7mm` high. But according to my math it should be about `15.5mm` (`1.552 = 44 * 2.54 * 1/72)`

What have I done wrong? Or do I misunderstand the `pt` unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use pts for anything but print.  It is specifically for print as 72pts = 1 inch.  Use %, px, or ems.

Here's a good article with a roundup of the different units and their uses.
http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what pt is for. What do you suggest then? Removing `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` and calculating with px the way I did with pt before (but 1/92 instead of 1/72)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the pixel density, e.g.

```
var devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
alert(devicePixelRaio);
```